# How do I separate a sentence after print?

Tags: madlib

I am a beginner. This is my code with the outcome in bold where the words are joined together. Question is how do I separate them after print?

adjective = input("Enter an adjective: ")

noun = input("Enter a noun: ")

verb = input("Enter a verb phrase: ")

adverb = input("Enter an adverb phrase: ")

sentence = "The " + adjective + noun + verb + adverb

print(sentence)

**The funnyfarmerate crabsat the dentist**

Answer (score 1):

this should do it:

```
sentence = "The " +adjective +" " +noun +" " +verb +" " +adverb +"."
print(sentence)
```

I hope your having fun learning python :)

Comment: It did work! 
No confidence but I am trying to like it :)